# How ISP knows how distribute responses among its clients?

Tags: sockets, ip

I have easy question. Just for understanding.

There is ISP (Provider) with external IP=111.222.333.444; 
there is web server on the IP=aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd;
ISP has 2 consumers (clients) with local IP=192.168.0.11 and IP=192.168.0.22 accordingly.

These clients at the same time (approximately) send different requests to the server, using port 80.

As I can imagine, ISP has some software that gathers all requests from its local network, and redirect them to web-servers from "own name", then scatters responses among clients.

So the server gets 2 requests:
request-a: from the socket 111.222.333.444:80,
request-b: from the socket 111.222.333.444:80.

Then server sends 2 responses (resp.-a and resp.-b) to the same socket: 111.222.333.444:80.

**Question**: how ISP-software distributes these responses among its clients? How it knows which response is for which client? How it avoid mixing of responses?

Thank you, and apologize for the naive question.

 Maybe just links where I can read shortly about it?

Comment: You're describing how TCP works. It doesn't have anything to do with the ISP having any magic software.

Comment: @EJP,  I just want to know how "router" (even WiFi router) can avoid **errors in distributing of responses**, if many clients send their requests to the same server at the same (~) time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The ISP is pretty irrelevant here, unless they're applying ISP-wide NAT. Otherwise they're just *routing* your data packets through a whole lot of different IP addresses.
2. It doesn't really matter though where the NATting is happening, if any. The problem is the same if you simply have two different browser tabs open on the same computer: how does each tab know which data is destined for it, especially if you're opening pages from the same server? And the answer is simple: ports.

   The *outgoing* port on your machine is not the same as the *incoming* port on the server you're sending your data to. You're sending a request *to* port 80, but it'll originate *from* some random port on your computer like 12345. Your computer remembers this port as belonging to a certain application (temporarily, until the connection is closed). The server will reply to your request with a data packet destined for your IP address and port 12345. NATs and proxies work exactly the same way.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand: the server assigns 2 different ports for these connections (1234 and 3456), and server's responses will be not 111.222.333.444:80 both, but 111.222.333.444:1234 and 111.222.333.444:3456. Thanks!

Comment: To be nitpicky: the server doesn't "assign" anything. An IP packet has a *sender* and a *receiver* address. The receiver address is the server's and targets port 80. The *sender's* port is randomly chosen by the sender itself. Only the sender needs to make sure itself that all the connections it's currently juggling have unique port numbers so it can associate the responses it gets. The server simply replies to the sender address it got the request from.

Comment: Thank you. So, if I understand right now, client-a creates request with ports (80,x), client-b creates request with ports (80,y), then router must re-assign these ports as (80,x') and (80,y') to avoid collision x=y, and server get now (80,x') and (80,y'). responses - same reversed way.

Comment: A *NAT* or *proxy* would have to rewrite those ports, a *router* simply forwards the packet without getting involved at all. A NAT or proxy essentially terminates the connection and opens a new one, so there's *server - proxy - you*. That's two different connections which both obey the mechanics of ports independently. Between the server and proxy and the proxy and you there are dozens of routers, which are not interested in ports at all and work on a lower level of the TCP/IP stack.